# YouTube Analytics API Refresh Token Limit

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, youtube-analytics-api

I created Refresh token to authenticate my YouTube Analytics API using Python and saved it on my system for future use. But after one week I have found that even the Refresh token is expired and again I have to authenticate the app using OAuth Consent screen. Is there a method to bypass this Refresh token expiry limit so that I could call the API without any further authentications?

```
if os.path.exists(self.token):
        print('Loading Credentials From File...')
        with open(self.token, 'rb') as token:
            self.credentials = pickle.load(token)


    if not self.credentials or not self.credentials.valid:

        if self.credentials and self.credentials.expired and self.credentials.refresh_token:
            
            print('Refreshing Access Token...')
            self.credentials.refresh(Request())
            
        else:
            
            print('Fetching New Tokens...')
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(self.secret_file, self.scopes)
            self.credentials = flow.run_console()

            print(self.credentials.to_json())

            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open(self.token, 'wb') as f:
                
                print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
                pickle.dump(self.credentials, f)
```

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnhVE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Causes for a refresh token expiring:

1. If the refresh token has not been used in six months it will expire automatically
2. if the user revokes your access in their account then the refresh token will expire.
3. Everytime a user authorizes to your application you will be granted a refresh token, sometimes when you refresh the access token a new refresh token will be returned to you.  You can have a max of 50 outstanding refresh tokens before the oldest one will expire.

I would double check that you are storing the most recent refresh token, and set up your code to handle an expired refresh token and request access of the user again.